# pthread_rwlock_destroy of a locked mutex

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, valgrind

When destroying a read/write lock, Helgrind reported the following error:

> pthread_rwlock_destroy of a locked mutex

Leaving aside the fact that it is a lock I am destroying, not a mutex (though the library’s implementation may rely on mutexes), the error is probably accurate, especially since a subsequent attempt to release the lock is flagged by Helgrind as releasing an invalid lock.

I understand that it is probably an error to destroy a lock that is still being held by another thread. (Locks are typically destroyed together with the resource they protect, and if the lock is being held, it means the resource is still in use and should not be destroyed).

Now my questions:

- Is it an error to destroy a lock that is still being held by the **current** thread?
- If so, what is the reasoning behind it?
- If so, how can I prevent other threads from acquiring the lock and messing with the resource when I am about to destroy both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it an error to destroy a lock that is still being held by the
>   current thread?

Yes, it is.  POSIX says:

> Results are undefined if `pthread_rwlock_destroy()` is called when any
>   thread holds `rwlock`.

This is clear - "any thread" includes the current thread.

The reasoning would be along these lines: Either another thread can be racing to take the lock with the current thread's `pthread_rwlock_destroy()`, or it cannot.  If it *can* be, then the program is already erroneous because attempting to lock an uninitialised lock is undefined; if it cannot, then it suffices for the current thread to unlock the lock first, then destroy it.

> If so, how can I prevent other threads from acquiring the lock and
>   messing with the resource when I am about to destroy both?

The reasoning above hints at the answer to this - to destroy the object, including the lock within it, you must *first* make it unreachable for any other thread.  You would do this by removing all references to it from other data structures, which likely involves taking and releasing other locks, but once you have the object itself isolated, you can safely unlock it because your thread must then hold the only remaining reference.